# Uploading my Node + HTML Canvas game to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I finished a small canvas based game and I would like to upload it to the web via Heroku.

All the code is written at the Src directory and I bundle it to the dist directory via Webpack. I then use a simple express server to serve the static files.

This is all there is to it:

[image]

On development mode this works just fine. However, when I upload to Heroku I get "Cannot GET /".

I tried several option to make this work but for some reason I'm not able to fix this.

I did try to write this as well:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
   res.sendFile('index.html');
}
```

or some variation of this but to no avail.

This is the scripts part of my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "webpack --watch",
    "prod": "webpack --config webpack.production.config.js -p"
  }
```

When I run on development I use "npm install" followed by "npm run prod" to bundle to 'dist' and then "npm start".

What am  I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you build the `dist` directory after `npm install`? Could you share the contents of your `package.json` file?

Comment: Yes, I do. I added the content of package.json to my original question.

Is this what is happening behind the scenes? Heroku doesn't bundle it?

Comment: It's possible. Heroku runs `npm install` automatically. To run the `prod` script you defined in your `package.json`, you'll need to define it as a `postinstall` script so Heroku would execute it immediately after `npm install`.

Comment: Ok, so first of all, following your advice I removed "/dist" from my .gitignore file and everything worked - So first of all thanks for that. 
Now, obviously I want to keep the /dist/ folder inside my .gitignore. I changed the package.json scripts part to "postinstall" instead of "prod". Now, when I upload to heroku via "git push heroku master:, I get "         sh: 1: webpack: not found" error. Any idea why? My webpack is installed under "devDependencies" if that matters.

Comment: Heroku can't find the location of the `webpack` binary. You could fix this by changing any reference to `webpack` in your `package.json` to `./node_modules/.bin/webpack`.

Comment: I get the same error here as well. I assume that this is because /node_modules/ are inside my .gitignore file as well. I'm mainly confused about the practice of uploading to production. Obviously I wouldn't want a tool like webpack to be uploaded to my server since it is just a development tool. With that said, how do I create a dist folder without it? If you can clarify that'd be great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123592/discussion-between-pashtidot-and-gnerkus).